# connecting scatterplot lines with missing values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Is there a way to create a scatterplot with lines connecting all points even when there is missing values in the dataset?
For example the plot below right now doesn't have a line connecting all the series1 points because there is a missing value. Is there a way to connect them? the only other solution to this issue was addressed using the base R plot() function not ggplot.

```
#generate fake dataset with three columns 'x', 'value', and 'variable'
data <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 3),
                   value=c(2,4,NA,6,2,3,5,4,3,6,9,7,4,3,5), 
                   variable=rep(paste0('series', 1:3), each=5))
data
#plot all three series on the same chart using geom_line()
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=value, group =variable)) + geom_line(colour = "black") + geom_point(aes(shape=variable, color=variable, fill = variable), size=2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 22, 23))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('black','black', 'black'))+
  scale_fill_manual(values= c('#999999','#E69F00', '#56B4E9')) +
  theme_classic() + theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1), legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(1,1)  ) + geom_vline(xintercept=3, linetype="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: You have to omit the rows with NAs in them.

Comment: There is an issue of data visualisation best practice to consider here. If you connect those points, you are making an assumption about the missing value, which is that you estimate its true value equals 5. Indeed, if the data is continuous then when you connect any two points you're assuming that the values between those points lie on the line. So you need to consider whether that's a reasonable assumption given your real data. The reason that `geom_line` doesn't connect the points is that it doesn't want to make that assumption for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a copy of your data frame without the `NA` values to `geom_line`. Something like:

```r
ggplot(data = data, aes(x, value, group = variable, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "black", data = data[complete.cases(data),]) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = variable), color = "black", size = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = "dotted")+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22, 23)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#999999','#E69F00', '#56B4E9')) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 1), 
        legend.justification = c(1, 1), 
        legend.position = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

Though personally, I think it's a bit hard to make out individual series, and I might go for direct labelling here:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x, value)) + 
  geom_textline(colour = "black", data = data[complete.cases(data),], size = 7,
            aes(linetype = variable, label = variable, hjust = variable)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = "dotted") +
  scale_hjust_manual(values = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.1)) +
  guides(linetype = "none") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 1), 
        legend.justification = c(1, 1), 
        legend.position = c(1, 1))
```

[image]